# Ignore Tag for Hot Network Questions

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, ignored-tags

When browsing a thematic Stack Exchange, e.g. physics Stack Exchange, on the bottom right corner we have a Hot Network Questions section. While I like this feature, there are some Stack Exchange which I have no interest in visiting and I wish I could get more links from the Exchanges I actually care about.

Is there a way to filter which Stack Exchanges we get recomandation from? I'm looking for something similar to an ignore tag, but for Stack Exchanges. The ideal outcome would be to not see anymore the links coming from ignored Stack Exchanges.